# Define foreach inside a method to avoid repetition

Tags: php

So I have two methods inside my class that are using the same `foreach` and they're being repeated within both methods .. Is there a best way to define foreach inside its own method? So I'd like to have the foreach called as `$this->loop` inside the methods, but then have the `foreach` inside a method called `public function loop()`.

All help would be appreciated.

So I have the two following methods inside my class:

```
public function check_missing_blobs(): void
    {
        $profiles = Profile::get([
            'meta_query' => [
                'relation' => 'OR',
                [
                    'key' => 'azure_picture',
                    'value' => '',
                    'compare' => '='
                ],
                [
                    'key' => 'azure_picture_big',
                    'value' => '',
                    'compare' => '='
                ],
            ]
        ]);

        if (count($profiles) === 0) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
            $profile->load([
                'azure_picture' => Azure::init()->set_blob_sas_url
                ($profile->get_employee_id()),
                'azure_picture_big' => Azure::init()->set_blob_sas_url
                ($profile->get_employee_id(), 'Big/'),
                'azure_picture_expiration' =>
                    $profile->set_azure_picture_expiration
                    (strtotime('+7 days')),
                'azure_picture_big_expiration' =>
                    $profile->set_azure_picture_big_expiration
                    (strtotime('+7 days')),
            ]);
            $profile->save();
        }
    }
```

AND:

```
public function check_blob_expiration(string $days = '+2 days'): bool
    {
        $key = 'check_blob_expiration';

        $settings = $this->get_settings($key);

        if ($settings->started <= $settings->finished) {
            $settings->started = time();
        }

        $profiles = Profile::get([
            'post_status' => [
                'publish', 'draft', 'pending', 'private'
            ],
            'posts_per_page' => 250,
            'meta_query' => [
                'relation' => 'OR',
                [
                    'key' => 'azure_picture_expiration',
                    'value' => strtotime($days),
                    'compare' => '<=',
                ],
                [
                    'key' => 'azure_picture_big_expiration',
                    'value' => strtotime($days),
                    'compare' => '<=',
                ],
            ],
            'paged' => $settings->page,
        ]);

        if (count($profiles) === 0) {
            $settings->page = 0;
            $settings->finished = time();
            echo '<pre>No azure blobs expiring within 2 days.</pre>';
            return $this->set_settings($key, $settings);
        }

        foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
            $profile->load([
                'azure_picture' => Azure::init()->set_blob_sas_url
                ($profile->get_employee_id()),
                'azure_picture_big' => Azure::init()->set_blob_sas_url
                ($profile->get_employee_id(), 'Big/'),
                'azure_picture_expiration' =>
                    $profile->set_azure_picture_expiration
                    (strtotime('+7 days')),
                'azure_picture_big_expiration' =>
                    $profile->set_azure_picture_big_expiration
                    (strtotime('+7 days')),
            ]);
            $profile->save();
        }

        if (!empty($profiles)) {
            $settings->page++;
        } else {
            $settings->page = 0;
            $settings->finished = time();
        }

        return $this->set_settings($key, $settings);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could envisage using a [trait](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

In short, a trait allows you to: *reuse sets of methods freely in several independent classes living in different class hierarchies.* (source: the manual).

An example to help better understand the concept:

1. Define a trait, call it e.g. `Iterate`, here it has one function `loop(array $arr)`
2. Inside the class where you want to use function `loop`, use: `use Iterate`
3. Now, as you can see, we can invoke the function: `$this->loop()` inside class `Test`

.

```
<?php

trait Iterate
{
    public function loop(array $arr)
    {
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            echo 'key : ' . $key;
            echo '<br />';
            echo 'value : ' . $value;
            echo '<br />';
        }
    }
}

class Test
{
    use Iterate;

    public function __construct($arr)
    {
        $this->loop($arr);
    }
}
$arr = [1, 2, 3];
$test = new Test($arr);
```

Output:

```
key : 0
value : 1
key : 1
value : 2
key : 2
value : 3
```

Comment: Ohh I forgot all about this! Let me test things out and I will touch basis soon!